# How do I cast a System.Windows.Control WebBrowser.Document to an mshtml.MSHTMLDocumentClass?

Tags: c#, html, .net, wpf, mshtml

I have a `WebBrowser` that loads inside a WPF window. I need to get the title of the web page loaded in the `WebBrowser`.

I get the document using

`object doc = this._browser.Document;` and I can see that it is an `mshtml.MSHTMLDocument` and I want to cast it as this type so that I can pull the title out, however I can't find this type in any .NET library.

Will I have to create the type myself or am I just looking in the wrong place/approaching this wrong way?

How can I pull the page title out of a `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser` Document?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Either add reference to `Microsoft.mshtml` and then:

```
var title = (webBrowser.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument).title;
```

or

```
dynamic doc = webBrowser.Document;
var title = doc.title;
```

Comment: which specific .dll contains Microsoft.mshtml?

Comment: If I go to Add Reference it will be under Extensions -> Miscosoft.mshtml

Comment: We must be using different versions of Visual Studio or different IDEs. I am using Visual Studio 2010 and I don't have Extensions as a tab under Add Reference. Out of curiosity, in what directory is it located on your computer? I am banging my head against my desk trying to find this one file on my system. Maybe I will get lucky and have the same path.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Common\Microsoft.mshtml.dll, also search for _Microsoft HTML Object Library_ as I suggested in one of my old answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618739/how-to-get-value-from-any-tag-in-web-browser-control-using-wpf/17619452#17619452)

Comment: Found it. The file was mshtml.tlb

Comment: VS22, it's found in `{Install Directory...}\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies`. To add DLLs, follow directions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65017892/.