# Select browser elements using WPF, XAML, and C#

Tags: c#, html, wpf, xaml

I'm working on a wpf project that includes a browser. Is there a way to use Visual Studio's builtin webbrowser control to fire off some event that indicates what specific element on the page a user has highlighted?

I want the user to be able to highlight (and mark) any text, table, cell, row, column, image, link, etc. in the browser windows so that I can extract the selected item (akin to a web scraper or spider but specific to user selections similar to copy/pasting in a word processing document)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618739/how-to-get-value-from-any-tag-in-web-browser-control-using-wpf

Comment: var myTagValue = (wbBrowser.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument)
                   .getElementsByTagName("CODE")
                   .OfType<mshtml.IHTMLElement>()
                   .First()
                   .innerText

Comment: Above code is what I found using you link(in this case looking for element named "Code") but I'm not sure how to use it (a newb). What event has to be fired to assign the value to variable?